# HCF of two numbers is 6. LCM of same numbers 72. What are two numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am a student and I need help answering this HCF an and LCM question.

The HCF of two numbers is 6. The LCM of the same numbers is 72. What are the two numbers?

Thank you and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$LCM \times HCF = \text{Product of two numbers}$$

Since their HCF is $6$, let the numbers be $6m$ and $6n$.

Now apply the formula. (Also note that $m$ and $n$ are coprime, i.e. $\gcd(m,n)=1$
)

You'll get :

$$6m \times 6n=6 \times 72  \implies mn=12 ~~; ~ m,n \in \mathbb N$$

Now the possible unordered pairs of $(m,n)$ are :
$$(1,12) ; (2,6) ; (3,4)$$

Out of which only the pair $(3,4)$ is coprime.

Hence, the numbers are : $18$ and $24$.

Comment: Also note that $m$ and $n$ are coprime

Comment: What does coprime mean

Comment: @OliviaAages See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers)

Comment: If m and n are coprime how do you work out m and n

Comment: M×n =72 and they also equal 1

Comment: @OliviaAages Is it clear?

Comment: Yes I have understood☺ I will use this method to answer these types of questions

Answer (score 1):

$72=2^3 \cdot 3^2$

So the two numbers must look like $x = 2^a \cdot 3^b$ and $y = 2^c \cdot 3^b$.

Since $\gcd(x,y)=6=2^1 \cdot 3^1$, then 
$$\text{$\min(a,c)=1$ and $\min(b,d)=1$}$$.

Since $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)=72=2^3 \cdot 3^2$, then 
$$\text{$\max(a,c)=3$ and $\max(b,d)=2$}$$

$$
\left \{
\begin{array}{c}
   \min(a,c)=1 \\
   \max(a,c)=3
\end{array}
\right \}
\implies \{a,c\}=\{1,3\}
\implies \{2^a, 2^c\}=\{2,8\}
$$

$$
\left \{
\begin{array}{c}
   \min(b,d)=1 \\
   \max(b,d)=2
\end{array}
\right \}
\implies \{b,d\}=\{1,2\}
\implies \{3^b, 3^d\} = \{3,9\}
$$

$$(x,y) \in \{ (6,72),(18,24),(24,18),(72,6) \}$$